# Alternative to Range.Characters to track down Font Formats within a single Cell

Tags: excel, vba

It is highly inefficient having to check char by char the styles of the text within a cell. Is there any other way to track it down?

A sample to reflect which the core issue is:

```
' omitted code of a function that receives a Cell as Range
For iChar = 1 To nChars
    Set Char = rnIn.Characters(iChar, 1)
    With Char.Font
            blnNoneActive = Not .Bold And Not .Italic And Not .Underline
            Changed = trackStyle(stNone, blnNoneActive, rnIn, iChar, colActiveStyles, colToActive, colToInactive)
            Changed = Changed Or trackStyle(stBold, .Bold, rnIn, iChar, colActiveStyles, colToActive, colToInactive)
            Changed = Changed Or trackStyle(stItalics, .Italic, rnIn, iChar, colActiveStyles, colToActive, colToInactive)
            blnUnderline = Not (.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone)
            Changed = Changed Or trackStyle(stUnderline, blnUnderline, rnIn, iChar, colActiveStyles, colToActive, colToInactive)
    End With
    ' Omitted code
Next
```

**EDIT**

I was thinking that perhaps accessing the file format directly could help to get a shortcut to the in-cell font formats. Is that possible?

Comment: are you checking if any format in a range changed? You can try `cellRange.Value(11)` (or `.Value(12)`) if you can make sense of the XML https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlrangevaluedatatype-enumeration-excel. Might be easier to save the range as .HTML and parse that.

Comment: sounds interesting... it might save a temporal file and use XML to parse. That surely could be faster when you got hundreds of in-cell formatted fonts... will look into that :) Thank you @Slai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cellRange.Value(11)` in combination with `Regexp` did the trick here, as suggested by Slai in the comments of the question.

This solution worked fast enough for the case that triggered the query. Shared here to give some directions. Hope that helps someone else.

Usage, in cell formula: `=ToMarkdown(A1)`

```
Option Explicit

' Pre-markdown 
Const bold_start = "_B_"
Const bold_end = "_nB_"
Const italics_start = "_I_"
Const italics_end = "_nI_"
Const under_start = "_U_"
Const under_end = "_nU_"

' Final Markdown
Const ch_bold = "**"
Const ch_italics = "_"
Const ch_u_start = "<_" ' underline start
Const ch_u_end = "_>"   ' underline end


Private pCache As Collection
Public pCachedRegexes As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 Set pCache = New Collection
End Sub

' Markdown only works when using Source as range
Public Function ToMarkdown(Source) As String
Dim rnIn As Range
Dim strXML_Source As String, strXML_Out As String
Dim strPreMarkdown As String
 On Error Resume Next

 If TypeName(Source) = "String" Then ToMarkdown = Source : Exit Function
 If Not (TypeName(Source) = "Range") Then Exit Function
 ' option only available if a Range has been provided
 Set rnIn = Source
 ToMarkdown = rnIn.Value

 ' save
 strXML_Source = rnIn.Value(11)
 strXML_Out = ReplaceXML_ByPreMarkdown(strXML_Source)

 Application.EnableEvents = False
 rnIn.Value(11) = strXML_Out
 strPreMarkdown = rnIn.Value
 ' restore
 rnIn.Value(11) = strXML_Source
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 ToMarkdown = ToFinalMarkdown(strPreMarkdown)
End Function

Private Function ReplaceXML_ByPreMarkdown(ByVal strXML As String) As String
Dim strPat As String
 On Error Resume Next

 strXML = Replace(strXML, "<B>", bold_start, Compare:=vbDatabaseCompare)
 strXML = Replace(strXML, "</B>", bold_end, Compare:=vbDatabaseCompare)
 strXML = Replace(strXML, "<I>", italics_start, Compare:=vbDatabaseCompare)
 strXML = Replace(strXML, "</I>", italics_end, Compare:=vbDatabaseCompare)
 strXML = Replace(strXML, "<U>", under_start, Compare:=vbDatabaseCompare)
 strXML = Replace(strXML, "</U>", under_end, Compare:=vbDatabaseCompare)

 ReplaceXML_ByPreMarkdown = strXML
End Function

Private Function getStyleCatchPattern(strFind As String) As String
 On Error Resume Next
 getStyleCatchPattern = "([ ]*(?:" & strFind & ")[ ]*)"
End Function

Private Function ToFinalMarkdown(strPreMarkdown) As String
Dim strOut As String, strPat As String
 On Error Resume Next
 strOut = strPreMarkdown

 ' Reorganizing blank spaces (pre-post delimiters)
 strPat = getStyleCatchPattern(bold_start)
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, " " & bold_start)
 strPat = getStyleCatchPattern(bold_end)
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, bold_end & " ")

 strPat = getStyleCatchPattern(italics_start)
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, " " & italics_start)
 strPat = getStyleCatchPattern(italics_end)
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, italics_end & " ")

 strPat = getStyleCatchPattern(under_start)
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, " " & under_start)
 strPat = getStyleCatchPattern(under_end)
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, under_end & " ")

 ' Final blank spaces adjustment (remove spaces between start/end delimiters)
 strPat = "(" & bold_start & "|" & italics_start & "|" & under_start & ")"
 strPat = strPat & "(\s+?)" & strPat
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, "$1$3")
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, "$1$3")

 strPat = "(" & bold_end & "|" & italics_end & "|" & under_end & ")"
 strPat = strPat & "(\s+?)" & strPat
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, "$1$3")
 strOut = RxReplace(strOut, strPat, "$1$3")

 ' To Final Markdown
 strOut = Replace(strOut, bold_start, ch_bold)
 strOut = Replace(strOut, bold_end, ch_bold)
 strOut = Replace(strOut, italics_start, ch_italics)
 strOut = Replace(strOut, italics_end, ch_italics)
 strOut = Replace(strOut, under_start, ch_u_start)
 strOut = Replace(strOut, under_end, ch_u_end)

 ToFinalMarkdown = strOut
End Function

' ********** RegExp with late binding 
Private Function GetRegex(Pattern As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, _ 
        Optional Multiline As Boolean = True, Optional MatchGlobal As Boolean = True) As Object

    If pCachedRegexes Is Nothing Then Set pCachedRegexes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Build the unique key for the regex (to Cache it)
    Dim rxKey As String
    rxKey = IIf(IgnoreCase, "1", "0") & _
            IIf(Multiline, "1", "0") & _
            IIf(MatchGlobal, "1", "0") & _
            Pattern

    If Not pCachedRegexes.Exists(rxKey) Then
        Dim oRegExp As Object
        Set oRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With oRegExp
            .Pattern = Pattern
            .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
            .Multiline = Multiline
            .Global = MatchGlobal
        End With
        Set pCachedRegexes(rxKey) = oRegExp
    End If

    ' Fetch and return the pre-compiled RegExp object
    Set GetRegex = pCachedRegexes(rxKey)
End Function

Private Function RxReplace(SourceString As String, Pattern As String, ReplacePattern As String, _
    Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional Multiline As Boolean = True, _
    Optional MatchGlobal As Boolean = True) As String

    RxReplace = GetRegex(Pattern, IgnoreCase, Multiline, MatchGlobal).Replace( _
        SourceString, ReplacePattern)
End Function
```